# Import rows in Fusion Tables fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I can't seem to import rows into Google Fusion correctly. I always get a 503 Backend error. My Google Apps Script code is below.

var getDataURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/*{tableID}*/import?key='+*{apiKey}*;

var ssDown = SpreadsheetApp.openById({Spreadsheet ID}).getDataRange().getValues();

var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "headers" : {
      "Authorization" : "Bearer " + *{token}*,
      "Accept" : "application/json",
    },
    'encoding' = 'auto-detect',
    'payload' = ssDown.toString();
  }
};

var output = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getDataURL,options).getContentText();

Comment: I've been seeing this backend error but on scripts nothing to do with Fusion tables. Take a look at issue 2759 ( https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2759 )

Comment: The response is coming from Fusion Tables, not GAS. I have copied the error below.


[13-05-19 11:18:20:362 BST] {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by careless coding on my part. The correct code is:

```
var getDataURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/{tableID}/import';
var options = { "method" : "post",
              "contentType" : "application/octet-stream",
              "headers" : {
                "Authorization" : "Bearer " + {token},
                "Accept" : "application/json",
              },
            }
var ssDown = SpreadsheetApp.openById({sheetID}).getDataRange().getValues().toString();
options.payload = ssDown;
var output = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getDataURL,options).getContentText();
```